# AVD emulator is not showing up in my Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Earlier this morning I started a beginner tutorial series on Android Studio. After setting up my virtual device, I hit run. Nothing happened. It says no emulators are currently running. I searched stack overflow and Reddit for solutions and did every single one of them. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling Android Studio. 12 hours later, the emulator is still not showing up. What could I do to fix this?

Comment: Does It show any error ? Virtualization is enabled in bios setting ?

Comment: @zephyr Its says No Running Emulators. It also says Gradle build finished. Tried to open BIOS setting and found out that Virtualization is already enabled. Still no luck :(